# Inheritance between the object and the class

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I create an object `sectionClass`.
I am using the following functions:

```
var extendOb = function (first, second) {
        for (property in second) {
            first[property] = second[property];
        } 
};
```

Moving the contents of a class object to a new class `sectionClass`, `widgetClass`.

So I have a copy of the object as if `sectionClass` class within each sub-object `widgetClass`.

The JS is the only references, so in theory it is not a problem.

Is this a good way to use inheritance / relationship between objects?
If not, what other way to get such comfort?

Another problem is what to do with such a situation.

I have to re-perform the function `extendOb` when I want to move an object to another class `widgetClass` `sectionClass` object.
How is it better to solve it?

Comment: It is unclear what problem you are trying to solve.  Please describe the actual result you are trying to achieve in words.  Your function `extendOb` is a means of copying properties from one object to another (that is all it does), but it is not a good general purpose way to implement inheritance (it might work in some simple situations, but not in others) - particularly when Javascript has more powerful ways of doing so.

Comment: What are the other ways? What are these better ways?

Comment: There are a gazillion articles on the web.  Any Google search will get you more reading material than you can consume.  Here's one good overall summary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript and something a bit more advanced: http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html